# The limits of a quadratic function

Tags: limits, quadratics

Here is the equation of the quadratic: $\dfrac{1}{10}x^2+3x+5$

Here is the graph visually:

[image]

I was wondering what value $y$ heads towards if the $x$ value is heading towards negative infinity.

My answer: infinity

For this, I looked at the negative $x$ values, then looked at their outputs. Their outputs seemed to be heading towards infinity. Is this the correct way of approaching this problem?

Comment: This is a great way to look at it from an intuitive perspective. If you want to get more involved in the formalism of what it means to "go to infinity," you can do that, but it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph, you can realize that as *x* goes toward negative infinity *f(x)* heading toward positive infinity. This limit is unbound or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

general equation of a quadratic is $ax^2+bx+c$. If a>0 it is a upward parabola, and if a<0 it is a downward parabola[image]

and coordinate of vertex of any parabola is ($\frac{-b}{2a},\frac{-d}{4a}$)
**so when it is a upward parabola it would have a min value
when it is a downward parabola it would have a maximum value**

Comment: The question is about $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\frac{1}{10}x^2 + 3x + 5\right)$$ which you have not addressed.